# OP07 - Input Bias Current vs. Differential Input Voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier

In [OP07's datasheet](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/OP07.pdf), i find the 'Input Bias Current vs. Differential Input Voltage' chart. Can anyone give some explanation about the chart. I notice OP07 has input protection diodes at the input. So i think the chart has some relations to these diodes.

[image]

1. The 'plateau' around zero differential input voltage corresponds to the case when the input diodes are off.
2. The straight slope line show it's 'resistive' beyond some input voltage.  So it correspond to the case when input protection diodes are on. The datasheet states the differential input resistance only 50M Ohm, but if i calculate from the chart, it shows the input series resistor R3 (or R4) will be 600M Ohm or so.

   Am i right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo. The 'Y' axis should be **mA** not nA!

The high resistance (M\$\Omega\$)applies to differential input voltages less than 1V (where the graph looks to be perfectly flat, at a scale of mA).

This is typical of this kind of bipolar super-\$\beta\$ input  op-amp. You should not generally use such an op-amp in applications with significant differential input voltage (such as a comparator or some kinds of precision rectifier).

So the resistors are more like 630\$\Omega\$ each. (14V/22mA)

From LTC's [datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/OP07.pdf):

[image]

If they were 600M the differential input noise due to (unavoidable) Johnson-Nyquist resistor noise would be about 500x higher than the OP07 typical spec.

Comment: There are 10^6 times error, a big mistake!! The 14V/22mA point come from the chart above, right? Are there other methods to find the input series resistor's value?

Comment: Yes, six orders of magnitude, and yes I read that off the graph. You could measure the resistance (modelling the back-to-back diodes or darlingtons across the inputs), but really any design that depends on the value of those resistors is suspect. They're **not** guaranteed so you should not **need** to know their value. Some op amps omit the resistance and require you to supply it externally if you insist in inflicting differential voltage on the inputs.

Comment: I logged in and submitted a request to Analog Devices to fix their datasheet. It's revision 'G' and the product is quite long in the tooth- surprising nobody has fixed it.